# Weird message when interacting with Azure via Powershell using username and password

Tags: linux, azure, powershell, azure-powershell, rhel8

Whenever I interact with Azure via PowerShell 7 using username and password, I get a weird message that Im not sure what it means. Ive googled it and havent really found anything about it. Also, im running powershell on RHEL 8. Interestingly, the script works regardless of the mesagae. Has anyone else experienced this and know what it means and how to resolve?

```
** Message: <time>: Remote error from secret service: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.secrets was not provided by any .service files
```

Comment: @[druffin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6207161/druffin), any update to the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In `~/.subversion/config` uncomment the password-stores entry and set it blank, the gnome and kde keyrings won't be used then (these are the programs giving you those errors).

You had to have either

```
password-stores=
```

or

```
password-stores =
```

One of them works, the other gives an error.
I tried with the `password-stores =` uncommenting and setting it to blank and worked fine.

***Note***: The `%APPDATA%Subversion` directory houses the runtime configuration settings for Subversion. The files are servers and configuration.